# Inserting a blank table row with a smaller height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table consisting of a header row and a couple of data rows. What I want to do is to create a blank row in between the header and the data rows, but I want this blank row to be smaller in height than the other rows (so that there isn't such a large gap).

How can I accomplish this?

My HTML mark-up code for the table is as follows:

```
<table class="action_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="header_row">
            <td>Header Item</td>
            <td>Header Item 2</td>
            <td>Header Item 3</td>
        </tr>            
        <tr class="blank_row">
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data_row">
            <td>Data Item</td>
            <td>Data Item 2</td>
            <td>Data Item 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Just add the CSS rule (and the slightly improved mark-up) posted below and you should get the result that you're after.

**CSS**

```
.blank_row
{
    height: 10px !important; /* overwrites any other rules */
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<tr class="blank_row">
    <td colspan="3"></td>
</tr>
```

Since I have no idea what your current stylesheet looks like I added the `!important` property just in case. If possible, though, you should remove it as one rarely wants to rely on `!important` declarations in a stylesheet considering the big possibility that they will mess it up later on.

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="line-height:10px;" colspan=3>&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: In XHTML 1.0 Strict, the `style=""` attribute is not autorized. Your code must be the same for any doctype.

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux Are you kidding? According to XHTML 1.0 Strict, the `style` attribute is the only correct attribute in Barry's example!

Comment: According to my course of HTML, in the XHTML Strict, we can't use the `style` attribute?

Comment: If they said it like that, they were wrong. They might have tried to convey that it's generally a better idea to put all styles together in a separate stylesheet, so you won't have to search through all your html sources if you want to change something. (No differences between HTML and XHTML there.) And sometimes, an inline style is simply the most convenient thing, for instance to avoid `!important` or circumstances like that.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need an extra table row to create space inside a table. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjWDP/).
(I made the gap light grey in colour, so you can see it, but you can change that to transparent.)

Using a table row just for display purposes is table abuse!

Comment: You're right and I like the elegance of your solution.  I need some separation else where in the table as well though.  So given the compatibility with my current coding, I'm going to take the easy way out.

Answer (score 8):

I know this question already has an answer, but I found out an even simpler way of doing this.

Just add

```
<tr height = 20px></tr>
```

Into the table where you want to have an empty row. It works fine in my program and it's probably the quickest solution possible.

Comment: Sorry but this is technically wrong. "height"  is not a valid  row attribute ! Example ref -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr  .  Apply a class as shown above.

Answer (score 7):

This one works for me:

```
<tr style="height: 15px;"/>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, and super-simple.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to achieve the same as asked in this question but accepted answer did not work for me in `May, 2018` (maybe answer is too old or some other reason). I am using `bootsrap 3.3.7` and `ionic v1`. 
You need to set `line-height` to do set height of specific row.

```css
.blank_row {
  line-height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table class="action_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="header_row">
      <td>Header Item</td>
      <td>Header Item 2</td>
      <td>Header Item 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="blank_row">
      <td bgcolor="#000" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data_row">
      <td>Data Item</td>
      <td>Data Item 2</td>
      <td>Data Item 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: using the white space alone (&nbsp;) triggered the row to space itself. This is by far a superior solution than manually setting the px, so I upvoted your solution over the picked.

Answer (score -3):

I couldn't get anything to work until I tried this simple line:

```
<p style="margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0; line-height:.5"><br /></p>
```

which allows you to vary a filler line height to your hearts content
(I was [probably MISusing Table to get three columns (boxes) of text which I then wanted to line up along the bottom)

I'm an amateur so would appreciate comments

Comment: I should have acknowledged the source: http://www.gokgs.com/help/_it_IT/EditorsTipsAndTricks.html - but they don't seem to have a contact route ... and it looks like it's some kinda high-powered game set-up ... and I've so far avoided that addictive route ever since staying up all night ~30 years ago with Space Invaders

Comment: FYI, when you want to have source code in your answer, indent that line with 4 spaces in the beginning
    This will allow you to have < > tags